# Why does my data not save in the Array

Tags: java

Can you tell me why it's not working, when i'll add an animal?
I worked before, when i added it to an ArrayList i created into the menu. But i would like to separate the BLL and UI.

Looking forward to hear from you guys :)

```
public class Animal
{

    private String name; //Name of animal
    private String kindOfAnimal; //Kind of animal
    private int currentAge; //Current age of animal
    private int expectedAge; //Expected lifetime

    private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

    public Animal(String name, String kindOfAnimal, int currentAge, int expectedAge)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.kindOfAnimal = kindOfAnimal;
        this.currentAge = currentAge;
        this.expectedAge = expectedAge;
        this.animals = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public int getExpectedAge()
    {
        return expectedAge;
    }

    public void setExpectedAge(int expectedAge)
    {
        this.expectedAge = expectedAge;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKindOfAnimal()
    {
        return kindOfAnimal;
    }

    public void setKindOfAnimal(String kindOfAnimal)
    {
        this.kindOfAnimal = kindOfAnimal;
    }

    public int getCurrentAge()
    {
        return currentAge;
    }

    public void setCurrentAge(int currentAge)
    {
        this.currentAge = currentAge;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "Type: " + getKindOfAnimal() + '\n'
                + "Name: " + getName() + '\n'
                + "Age: " + getCurrentAge() + '\n'
                + "Lifetime: " + getExpectedAge();
    }

    public void setAnimalList(Animal animal)
    {
        animals.add(animal);
    }

    public List<Animal> getAnimals()
    {
        return animals;
    }
}
```

Menu class

```
   public Menu()
    {
        menu();
    }

    public void menu()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please type in a number and press enter");
        System.out.println("1. Add animal");
        System.out.println("2. Show animals");

        if (sc.hasNextInt())
        {
            int input = sc.nextInt();

            if (input >= 0 && input < 10)
            {
                if (input == 1)
                {
                    addAnimal();
                }
                else if (input == 2)
                {
                    showAnimals();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number between the range");
                menu();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong input, please input a number!");
            menu();
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    private void addAnimal()
    {
        System.out.println("ADD ANIMAL");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try
        {
        System.out.println("Name: ");
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Kind of animal: ");
        String kindOfAnimal = sc.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Current age: ");
        int currentAge = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Expected age: ");
        int expectedAge = sc.nextInt();

        Animal animal = new Animal(name, kindOfAnimal, currentAge, expectedAge);

//        animals.add(animal.toString());

        animal.setAnimalList(animal);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the correct information");
        }
        System.out.println();
        menu();
    }

    public void showAnimals()

    {

            Animal animal = new Animal(null, null, 1, 1);

        if (animal.getAnimals().isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("There is no animals yet!");
            menu();
        }
        else
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < animal.getAnimals().size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(animal.getAnimals());

        }
        menu();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problems lies in this line inside of `showAnimals()`:

```
Animal animal = new Animal(null, null, 1, 1);
```

The thing is that you are creating a new list with that line of code every time you want to display a list of animals. So, it always comes out empty.

Try moving your list of animals from the `Animal` class into the `Menu` class. That way you will only have one copy of the list, and where you can add and display or animals from.

```
public class Menu {

private List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();

  public Menu()
  {
    menu();
  }


etc...


  private void addAnimal()
  {
    System.out.println("ADD ANIMAL");
    System.out.println();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    try
    {
      System.out.println("Name: ");
      String name = sc.nextLine();

      System.out.println("Kind of animal: ");
      String kindOfAnimal = sc.nextLine();


      System.out.println("Current age: ");
      int currentAge = sc.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Expected age: ");
      int expectedAge = sc.nextInt();

      Animal animal = new Animal(name, kindOfAnimal, currentAge, expectedAge);

      animals.add(animal);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter the correct information");
    }

    System.out.println();
    menu();
}

  public void showAnimals()
  {
    if (animals.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("There is no animals yet!");
        menu();
    }
    else
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++)
      {
        System.out.println(animals.get(i));
      }
      menu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Malinator.
I already got it to work by doing it in that way. But wouldn't it be better to keep the ArrayList away from the menu class? And keep it inside the Animal, and then use getters and setters to set and return values.

Comment: @Jakob If you want to keep it in the `Animal` class, then to make it work, you would have to make the list static.That is not the best of practices. I also agree with you that it doesn't belong to the `Menu` class, like you said. Maybe create a separate class to manage this list, like the `Zoo` class suggested by @Eran ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a separate list of animals in each instance of your `Animal` class, so each of those lists would have just one animal.

It would make more sense to keep the list of `Animal`s in a different class (perhaps a `Zoo` class?).